# gwt graphics and gwt beginner- unable to display a raster image on screen

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am trying to add an image to the canvas, and later plan to rotate the image.

This is the code I am using---

```
            RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

    DrawingArea canvas = new DrawingArea(800, 800);

    Image img= new Image(100, 100, 141, 538, "images/bottle.jpg");
    canvas.add(img);
    RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
```

I have stored the image in "war/images/bottle.jpg"... But no image is being shown when I try to run the project as a Google Web Application- I am using Eclipse IDE with GWT and Google Plugins for Eclipse installed.

What am I doing wrong here? Is the location to store images different by default? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location is correct, but you probably need to correct the path to the image. To do this prefix the path to your image with `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()` :

```
Image img= new Image(100, 100, 141, 538, GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "images/bottle.jpg");
```